# Using a Subquery in the Against for a FULLTEXT search in Mysql

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, subquery

In MySQL, I would like to do a FULLTEXT search on a table 'articles'.  The text I want to search against would be located in another table, 'Vectors' under the column 'CVs'

I am trying:

```
SELECT website 
FROM articles
WHERE MATCH (title, body)
AGAINST(
    SELECT CVs
    FROM Vectors
    WHERE Title="cv1")
```

However, it keeps returning syntax error.

Is it possible to run a subquery in the AGAINST clause?

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like:

```
SET @search = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CVs SEPARATOR " ") FROM Vectors WHERE Title="cv1") ;
SELECT website  FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title, body) AGAINST((@search) IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would like to be able to do:

```
SELECT website 
FROM articles cross join
     vectors
WHERE title = 'cv1' and MATCH (title, body) AGAINST(cv);
```

But, the argment in `against` needs to be a constant.

You can resort to:

```
SELECT website 
FROM articles cross join
     vectors
WHERE title = 'cv1' and
      (title like concat('%', cv, '%') or body like concat('%', cv, '%'))
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match)

```
The search string must be a literal string, not a variable or a column name.
```

You probably need to use LIKE instead of MATCH, though you should note that it will be much slower.