# mysql match against values from a table

Tags: php, mysql

I found a couple of questions with the same basic heading - but not the same question

i have a **content** table :

```
contentid
contentbody
```

i have a **keyword** table:

```
keywordid
keywordgroupid
keywordbody
```

i have a **keywordgroup** table:

```
keywordgroupid
keywordgroupbody
```

a normail query will look like this:

```
SELECT `contentid`,`contentbody` MATCH(`contentbody`) AGAINST ('whateverkeyword')
```

and i want to do a query like this:
how ever i want to the replace the 'whateverkeyword' with the results of a query e.g.

```
SELECT `keywordbody` FROM `keywordgroup` WHERE `keywordgroupid`=1
```

the idea is that the user selects a keyword group which is stored in the keyword table for instance if this was a person skills database you would have:

programmer keyword group that would have as keywords: logical,focused,technical

sales person keyword group that would have as keywords: people skills,friendly,outgoing

etc.

essentially I want to have a dynamic match value any ideas?

Comment: can you explain more

Comment: He's provided enough.  Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735562/using-a-subquery-in-the-against-for-a-fulltext-search-in-mysql

Comment: AGAINST MUST be a string literal, you cannot use a column value, therefore you cannot use a subselect (query result).